# The simplification of the classes are similar

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, return

I have class `MainModel` with inner classes `MainModelBase`, `ContractModel`, `WorkerModel`. The last two are essentially the same. Their differences in the implementation of the two methods and the return value for a number of methods.

`DeleteContract()` and `DeleteWorker()` are different code (`LoadPage()` is also). But `ReloadPage()`, `FirstPage()` and so on - are same. Difference in return value.

Can I simplify this porting code into `MainModelBase`? Does it make sense?

The whole code takes more than 300 lines. So here structure. Full code [here](https://github.com/c0rkin/StackShare/blob/master/MainModel.cs)

```
public class ContractModel : MainModelBase
{
    public ContractModel()


    internal bool DeleteContract(int id)

    internal List<ContractTableRow> ReloadPage()
    internal List<ContractTableRow> FirstPage()
    internal List<ContractTableRow> LastPage()
    internal List<ContractTableRow> NextPage()
    internal List<ContractTableRow> PreviousPage()
    internal List<ContractTableRow> CustomPage(int customPage)

    private List<ContractTableRow> LoadPage()
}

public class WorkerModel : MainModelBase
{
    public WorkerModel()

    internal bool DeleteWorker(int id)

    internal List<WorkerTableRow> ReloadPage()
    internal List<WorkerTableRow> FirstPage()
    internal List<WorkerTableRow> LastPage()
    internal List<WorkerTableRow> NextPage()
    internal List<WorkerTableRow> PreviousPage()
    internal List<WorkerTableRow> CustomPage(int customPage)

    private List<WorkerTableRow> LoadPage()
}

public class MainModelBase
{
    private int count;

    internal int MaxPage 
    internal int MinPage 
    internal int Count 
    internal int Size 
    internal int Page 
    internal string NumPageText 


    internal void Added()

    private int GetMaxPage()
}
```

**UPDATE**

The method `CustomPage()` calls `LoadPage()`, but it different for each class (`Delete()` also).

Is it right to do so?

```
public class ContractModel : PagedModelBase<ContractTableRow>
{
    public ContractModel()

    internal override bool Delete(int id)
    internal override List<ContractTableRow> LoadPage()
}

public class WorkerModel : PagedModelBase<WorkerTableRow>
{
    public WorkerModel()

    internal override bool Delete(int id)
    internal override List<WorkerTableRow> LoadPage()

}

public abstract class PagedModelBase<T>
{
    internal void Added()
    internal abstract bool Delete(int id);

    internal List<T> ReloadPage()
    internal List<T> FirstPage()
    internal List<T> LastPage()
    internal List<T> NextPage()
    internal List<T> PreviousPage()
    internal List<T> CustomPage(int customPage)

    internal abstract List<T> LoadPage();

    private int GetMaxPage()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a good candidate for using generics:

```
public class PagedModelBase<T> : MainModelBase
{
    internal bool Delete(int id)

    internal List<T> ReloadPage()
    internal List<T> FirstPage()
    internal List<T> LastPage()
    internal List<T> NextPage()
    internal List<T> PreviousPage()
    internal List<T> CustomPage(int customPage)

    private List<T> LoadPage()
}

public class ContractModel : PagedModelBase<ContractTableRow> 
{
    // contract specific implementation here
}

public class WorkerModel : PagedModelBase<WorkerTableRow>
{
    // worker specific implementation here
}
```